# Is there any way by which I can make webapps open in a new tab instead of a new window?

Tags: 12.10, webapps

I have installed these Webapps in my Ubuntu 12.10: Facebook, GMail, YouTube and they work fine. However while launching the website from the corresponding Webapp, it always opens in a new window of my default browser. Is there any way by which I can make them to open in a new tab instead of a new window?

Comment: In my 12.10 the opposite happens, webapps ony open in new tabs, which I find annoying because then the webapps is tied to the main browser windows and it doesn't feel like an app really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a nice workaround for Firefox. Install the [Tab Mix plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) add-on and check "Enable Single Window Mode" in its options.
[image: Enable Single Window Mode]

Comment: This is a nice work-around!

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand opening the Web Apps as **new tabs** *instead of* **new windows** is not currently supported, on the [Canonical blog](http://blog.canonical.com/2012/07/19/introducing-ubuntu-web-apps-setting-the-web-free-of-the-browser/) they explained the rationale as;

> At OSCON today, Mark Shuttleworth revealed Ubuntu Web Apps, a new
>   feature due to land in October’s Ubuntu 12.10 release. It will enable
>   Ubuntu users to run online applications like Facebook, Twitter,
>   Last.FM, Ebay and GMail direct from the desktop. Making web
>   applications behave like their desktop counterparts improves the user
>   experience dramatically; it’s faster and it reduces the proliferation
>   of browser tabs and windows that can quickly make a desktop
>   unmanageable.

Of course you can drag the open web app to your browser and there is will sit like any other tab (I have done this while testing with Chromium) but I am not aware of a way to open it with that behaviour by default.

Comment: on my setup, webapps ONLY open in new tabs. Maybe this is just a browser setting?

Comment: May be there can be some workaround possible. Also there are various bugs in current implementation, so I am thinking of uninstalling it for now.

Answer (score 1):

This bug was posted on launchpad.net [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/libunity-webapps/+bug/1113353).